# Origine di "Mettigli il sale sulla coda"

Tags: idioms, phrase-origin

Ho provato più volte a cercare l'origine del modo di dire "Mettere il sale sulla coda". Non sono mai riuscito a trovare una spiegazione di nessun tipo, tranne una volta un forum post in cui qualcuno diceva che appoggiando delicatamente una manciata di sale grosso sulla coda di un pollo, si ottiene che quello smette di andare a giro. Onestamente non ci ho creduto (ma non ho nemmeno provato).

Ho sempre pensato fosse una cosa italiana. Recentemente sto cominciando a capire che invece probabilmente il detto è internazionale e vecchiotto: un paio di mesi fa ho notato che in uno dei primi cartoni di Bugs Bunny, Elmer Fudd cerca di catturare Bugs mentre dorme, mettendogli del sale sulla coda (e mostra la saliera al pubblico nel fare ciò, e questa dice "salt"). Penso il cartone sia dei primi anni 1940.

Nell'etichetta di un noto sale sudafricano (Cerebos, [foto](https://www.flickr.com/photos/h_is_for_home/4112821329)) si vede un bambino o una bambina (dipende dalla versione) che corre dietro ad un pollo versandogli addosso del sale da una saliera. Come riferimento per la datazione ho trovato questo

> Cerebos has been an iconic South African brand since 1945. It traces its roots back to England in 1892 when a chemist decided to mix calcium phosphate with salt to mend his daughter's weak bones.

(dal sito della Cerebos)

---

Come suggerito nelle risposte di @abarisone e @Charo, conosco bene (essendone ovviamente io stesso stato oggetto ...anta anni fa) l'usanza di dirlo ai bimbi piccini come "consiglio" riguardo alla cattura di vari passerotti e piccioni ai giardini. Ma senza con questo voler mancare di rispetto, non mi trovo molto convinto sull'origine proposta (che il detto origini nell'uso che se ne fa con i bimbi).

Trovo la storia poco convincente perché "a priori" l'azione di mettere il sale sulla coda di un uccello appare (almeno nella cultura odierna) completamente aleatoria. Non so come dire, indipendentemente dal fatto che riuscirci ovviamente non è facilissimo, mi pare il vero problema sia che l'atto in sé è assurdo: è come se uno dicesse "spalmagli il burro sull'occhio". Dato un individuo raziocinante, come gli verrebbe in mente di fare una cosa del genere? Perché una persona andando a caccia di uccelli avrebbe mai del sale a portata di mano? Sopratutto nell'antichità, quando il sale era cosa preziosa e certamente non da sprecare? E poi perché non una manciata di ghiaia?

L'unica altra espressione legata al sale ed alla stasi che mi viene in mente è dalle *Fiabe Italiane* curate da Italo Calvino:

> C’era un Re con tre figlie femmine. Andò alla fiera e prima di partire
>   domandò alle figlie che regalo volevano. Una disse un fazzolettone, l’altra un
>   paio di stivaletti, la terza disse un cartoccio di sale. Le prime due sorelle che
>   non potevano vedere la più piccina, dissero al padre: - Lo sapete perché v’ha
>   chiesto il sale, quella birbante? Perché vuol salarvi le cuoia.
>   – Ah, sì! – disse il padre. – A me vuol salare le cuoia? E io la caccio di casa,
>   - e così fece

(da *Pelle di vecchia*, Montale Pistoiese)

L'inferenza è che la salatura delle cuoia sia un atto legato al processo di conciatura delle pelli (le cuoia, forma neutra del plurale di cuoio, toscanismo tipico). Ovviamente in questo piú che stasi momentanea si tratta di morte.

In effetti Wikipedia conferma ([pagina sulla Concia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concia)):

> La conservazione deve essere effettuata il più rapidamente possibile e consiste nel creare all'interno della pelle condizioni tali da rendere impossibile la vita e lo sviluppo di batteri e microorganismi che producono gli enzimi della putrefazione.
>
> I metodi di gran lunga più utilizzati sono la salatura e l'essiccamento.

Answer (score 3):

[Zanichelli](https://dizionaripiu.zanichelli.it/la-parola-e-servita/mettere-il-sale-sulla-coda/) fornisce una spiegazione interessante sulla possibile origine della locuzione oggetto della domanda:

> Perché dunque mettendo il sale sulla coda di qualcuno lo si blocca, lo
>   si cattura? Potremmo forse pensare all’immagine biblica della moglie
>   di Lot che, durante la distruzione di Sodoma e Gomorra, fu trasformata
>   in statua di sale per essersi voltata indietro a guardare (Genesi, 19,
>   26). Ma la strada non è questa e pare sia proprio quella indicata da
>   Neerea, e cioè al consiglio, scherzoso e inutile, dato ai bambini di
>   poter acciuffare gli uccellini che stanno rincorrendo mettendo ai
>   malcapitati volatili del sale sulla coda. E’ evidente che nel momento
>   in cui i bambini riuscissero a mettere del sale sulla coda agli
>   uccellini significherebbe che li avrebbero già presi e ben serrati
>   nelle loro mani!

Anche il forum *[Scioglilingua del Corriere della Sera](http://forum.corriere.it/scioglilingua/14-12-2009/mettere-il-sale-sulla-coda-1428817.html)* sembra concordare:

> Concordo sul significato attualmente attribuito, anche se in origine
>   questo aveva una connotazione unicamente ironica e beffarda. Era
>   questo, infatti, un metodo che si suggeriva ai bambini per acchiappere
>   gli uccellini, i quali, dopo, non potendo più volare, si sarebbero
>   potuti facilmente afferrare. Pertanto, fuori contesto, la frase veniva
>   ironicamente usata per intendere un'azione apparentemente facile da
>   realizzare, ma impossibile da eseguire.

Da [questo blog](http://il-trafiletto.blogspot.com/2014/01/perche-si-dice-mettere-il-sale-sulla.html?m=1) un’ulteriore curiosità:

> Giuseppe Gioacchino Belli fa uso di questa espressione in un suo
>   sonetto del 1832, La Santissima Ternità, parlando della colomba dello
>   Spirito Santo che vola via: "E allora sti dottori de la bbroda currino
>   appresso a mmetteje cor guanto un pizzico de sale in zu la coda".

Answer (score 2):

Secondo il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI17/GDLI_17_ocr_405.pdf&parola=sale%20sulla%20coda), l'orgine di questo modo di dire è lo scherzo popolare che suggerisce di cercar di catturare gli uccelli con questa tecnica:

> con  riferimento allo  scherzoso  suggerimento  popolare  di  adottare 
>   tale tecnica per catturare gli uccelli.

Questo modo di dire si usava già nella lingua italiana nella prima metà dell'Ottocento, da quanto si può dedurre dalla citazione dal racconto [*Margherita Pusterla* di Andrea Cantù](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI_indice_autori/GDLI_Indice_autori_65.pdf), edito nel 1838, che appare in tale dizionario (vedi anche  [qui](https://books.google.es/books?id=4N10sfoZhG8C&pg=PA464&lpg=PA464)):

> Alpinolo  per  tutti  i  dì  successivi  non  si 
>   diede  pace,  ricercandolo  in  ogni  canto,  appostandolo  su tutte  le  vie...:  «Che  credete,  che  Pisa sia un orto?  biso­gnava mettergli un grano di sale sulla coda».